# Can you actually put a link over <button> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I've been using HTML5 for a long time, and a while ago, I was making my project (login/register page project), I wanted to make a button that whenever I click the button, it'll redirect me to another HTML page, now I know about the `<a></a>` tag. And I know I can make the `<a></a>` tag as a button using bootstrap 5. But can you put a link in `<button></button>` tag?

Maybe using Javascript? And if there is a way to do that, can you explain how it works to me?

Comment: Wrong question: HTML elements are just DOM nodes, and they look like what they look like because of CSS. You pick the ones that semantically match what you need, so if you need a link to another page and that needs to looks like a button: use an `<a>` element because that's the right one, and then style it to look like a button using CSS. You don't need to wrap it in anything, just give it a `class="btn"` and then define a corresponding `a.btn { ... }` in your CSS that sets the border, border-radius, background color, etc. to whatever you want it to look like.

Comment: you can add onclick event in button and do redirect via java script

Comment: You can put a link around the button tag, sure, then it's just a button which is a link. It doesn't need to be inside the button tag.

Comment: When you want to have a link, you are essentially looking to perform an "action" of redirecting a user to a new web URL. The same thing can be done by adding the "onClick" function on a button. Hence, if you are looking for adding action, then you should use either href or button's onClick

Answer (score 3):

It's better to just do an  tag that is styled like a button.

```
<a href="/[YOUR LINK HERE]" class="button">Button</a>
```

And then style your button

```
.button {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    font: Arial 12px;
}
```

And whatever other style properties you need

Comment: Protip: `appearance: button;`

Answer (score -1):

You can do that.

But I guess it's semantically is wrong.

```html
<a href="link-here">
  <button>Click here</button>
 </a>
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) buttons can have like a parent any element that is type phrasing content. And the tag `<a></a>` isn't that type.
But are a [note from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content):

> A few other elements belong to this category (phrasing content), but only if a specific condition is fulfilled: `<a>`, if it contains only phrasing content

And `<button>` is Phrasing Content. So you can do this.

I let here my suggestion:

```js
function openLink(url) {
  window.open(url, '_blank')
}
```

```html
<button onclick="window.open('URL HERE', '_blank')">Click here</button>
<h1>Or</h1>
<button onclick="openLink('URL HERE')">Click here</button>
```

Attempt to `window.location` will load a new page at the same tab, and with `window.open()` open a new tab or browser window.

See:
[Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)
[Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)
[`<a>`: The Anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Answer (score -2):

you can't put a link in the `<button></button>` tag, but there is how you can redirect the browser url in javascript:

```js
const url = "/[your url]";

const button = document.querySelector("button[type='button']");
button.addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location = url;
});
```

```html
<button type="button">button</button>
```

Comment: You can do that, and it might be what the questioner is looking for, but you shouldn’t do that (:

Comment: I downvoted this answer because this answer contains _bad advice_: it breaks links for users without JS enabled, it means users can't middle-click on things to open links in new tabs/windows, and it isn't discoverable by bots/spiders, etc. Vision-impaired users with screen-readers will be told there's an action-button they can click (which should "do" something _other than_ just navigating to a new page), etc.